spring-data-jpa：How to mapping one entity to 2 different tables？
Backgroud：
I have two different tables in one DB，one is user_uat,the other is user_prod.I use spring-data-jpa to access my db.
Issues:
Actually user_uat and user_prod is in the same db, if I want to use api which generated by spring-data-jpa, I need to declare two entities which are same! This too weird.
Expect:
I want to access these two tables by one logic.This means our program should judge which env run in now,then base on the env to mapping entity to the corresponding table in db.Any idea? Please!
CREATE VIEW user_combined AS SELECT *, 'prod' AS source FROM user_prod UNION ALL SELECT *, 'uat' AS source FROM user_uat;
I tried to create a view and declare attribute env in class User, but I am not sure if spring-data-jpa Api could run well in 2 logic.
